# Normal Vector to from a line equation

Tags: vectors, orthogonality

I've been thinking about ways to get a normal vector from a line equation in $R^3$, 
and just got me brainstorming with vector products (did not go well), or the parametric equation of a line, because I can indeed get a normal vector from the equations in $R^2$:

($x1-p1$)/$d1$  =  $(x2-p2)/d2$

So I can put the $x1$ and $x2$ in the same side and I got an equation similar to $N.x$=$N.p$

But in $R^3$ just got messy, and I could not manage to work with 3 equalities.

Are there any other more intuitive ways to get a normal vector from a line equation in $R^3$ ?

The way I made it work was with the definition of orthogonality, but I hope surely thats an alternative way.

Thanks in advance guys, here is what I've got:

[image]

Comment: There needn't be a single normal direction to a line in $\mathbb{R}^3$. What is the direction of a line in $\mathbb{R}^3$ given by?

Comment: @OnceUponACrinoid indeed, I can choose to get x1 in function of x2 and x3, and so with the others. The direction of a line in $R^3$ is given by its direction vector, so similar to $R^2$ that I get two ways to interpret a normal line in $R^3$ I would have 3, am I right ?